# ARM time measurement

Tags: arm

On page 10 in the [this article](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2505.pdf) there is an example of time measurement with AVR. Is the same thing possible to do with [this](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/ARM/SAM3S.aspx)?

Comment: Yes is probably the correct answer because they both have timer capture / compare. But rather than expect everyone to sift through long datasheets it'd be better to mention the parts in your question and also mention if after reading both if there's a specific reason you don't think it'd be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the SAM3S M3 Cortex based micro will be able to perform various timer and compare functions, it has quite a sophisticated peripheral with up to 6 16-bit channels, which can also do event counting, frequency measurement, quadrature decoding, etc.
The details are in section 35 (pg.721) of the [SAM3S datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel_6500_32-bit-Cortex-M3-Microcontroller_SAM3S_Datasheet.pdf).